# Spring Async issue: New thread only created with Autowired instance, but not the one created "new"

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

Tried the Async demo project: https://github.com/huanzi-qch/springBoot/tree/master/springboot-async. It works fine to me. But turns out that if the instance is created by "new" keyword, the method with "Async" annotation will be executed in the same thread!! What is the reason for this different behavor?

```
@Autowired
private TestService testService;
...
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "：开始调用异步业务");
//无返回值
//TestService testService = new TestServiceImpl();  // If uncomment this line, no new thread created
testService.asyncTask();
```

Comment: `@Async` is implemented using AOP, which uses proxies. AOP, with Spring, only works on spring managed beans. If you create a new instance yourself that isn't spring managed.

Comment: @M.Deinum, Noted. Thanks for the explanation.